# VS Code Server taking up lots of Temp Space

Tags: vscode-remote

My setup is 2 systems: 1 Local system 1 Remote system. Local is running windows 11 and remtoe is running Windows 10

So, I've recently ran out of space on the remote system. After investigating I found that C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Temp was using over 80 gigs of space!

After further investigation I found folder after folder with 'vscode-server-win32-x64' inside.

After doing some looking, it seems like whenever I am connecting via VS Code remote SSH server, the system is downloading and attempting to install the vscode server. Which seems to lead to every connection attempt downloading a new copy into that temp folder.

Has anyone seen this or have any idea waht's going on?